# How to wrap Sharepoint Calendar Cell Row Text

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-online

How do I make long event titles wrap in Calendar cells if they are longer than cell width when viewing event list in Calendar view? I am in Sharepoint Online/2019.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I tested is setting below CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-rootdiv div {  
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this for a event list as Calendar view or when you drag a calendar widget on a page and then you add CSS module widget to page? What version of Sharepoint was this last working in?

Comment: OOB calendar view in SharePoint online(inject the CSS  by script editor webpart).

Comment: Do you mean you dragged a calendar widget on a page and then put a CSS widget on same page?